# strsplit in R with a metacharacter

Tags: string, r, split, strsplit, metacharacters

I have a large amount of data where the delimiter is a backslash. I'm processing it in R  and I'm having a hard time finding how to split the string since the backslash is a metacharacter. For example, a string would look like this:

```
1128\0019\XA5\E2R\366\00=15
```

and I want to split it along the `\` character, but when I run the strsplit command:

```
strsplit(tempStr, "\\")
Error in strsplit(tempStr, "\\") : 
  invalid regular expression '\', reason 'Trailing backslash'
```

When I try to used the "fixed" option, it does not run because it is expecting something after the backslash:

```
strsplit(tempStr, "\", fixed = TRUE)
```

Unfortunately, I can't preprocess the data with another program because the data is generated daily.

Answer (score 14):

Your line of code is (though you don't say it explicitly):

```
strsplit(tempStr, "\\")
```

and should be

```
strsplit(tempStr, "\\\\")
```

This will be read as "\\", which the regular expression will understand as a "\".

Comment: unfortunately this is not working... I just get the same string back. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide a self-contained example (that is, get it into R code so we can run it?)

Comment: Aye, same problem... when I do \\\\, it removes any occurrences of double slash, but \\ gets the above error, and \\\ tries to escape the following quote mark...

Comment: @JoshuaEricTurcotte could you provide a self-contained example?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that your data is in a file of some sort. If this is the case, then use `read.table` but specify the delimiter explicitly. For example, suppose your file was:

```
a\b\c\d
e\f\g\h
```

then to read this into R, use the command:

```
read.table("file.txt", sep="\\")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
strsplit(tempStr, "\"")
```